# Calculate the rate of change in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I need to calculate the rate of change in drug usage between two dates using SSRS.  I am used to using SQL, therefore I am having a difficult time with SSRS.

I have the following information:

```
                             Avg_Alcohol_Use_Month   Avg_Drug_Use_Month 
First_interview_Date              1.63%                    1.34%
      1/30/2017

Followup_interview_date           2.58%                     .80%
      6/30/2017
```

How do I create a report that reflects the rate of change in drug usage between two dates?  I need to create the report in SSRS but, I don't know how to write a query in SSRS that will reflect the rate of change.

I cannot create the query in SQL because I only have access to the data through SSRS.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I'm not sure what you're hoping for. (expression help, calculated field, dataset)

Comment: If you are more comfortable using SQL then it's probably easier to just do the work in your dataset as that will be plain SQL. SSRS expressions work on the data provided by the dataset which in turn (usually) is data retrieved from a query or stored proc from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

(This example is for SQL Server)

You can do it in SQL if you save the initial results in a table or a temp data structure.  If you subquery, you can subtract the line's rates by the previous line's rate.  This is by date, so you chose the MAX(date) for the given patient/doctor, whatever that (Primary Key?) is. In this case I have used "PatientID" to identify the patient.  See below:

```
--Assume your values are saved in a table or other temp table
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (PatientID int, Interview_Date date, Avg_Alcohol_Use_Month decimal (4,2), Avg_Drug_Use_Month decimal (4,2))
INSERT INTO @tmp 
VALUES
 (1, '2017-01-30', 1.63, 1.34)
,(2, '2017-06-30', 2.58, 0.80)
,(1, '2017-03-01', 1.54, 1.23)
,(1, '2017-07-02', 3.21, 0.20)
,(2, '2017-08-23', 2.10, 4.52)

SELECT PatientID
      ,Interview_Date
      ,Avg_Alcohol_Use_Month
      ,Avg_Drug_Use_Month
      ,Avg_Alcohol_Use_Month
       -
       (SELECT Avg_Alcohol_Use_Month
          FROM @tmp T2
         WHERE T2.PatientID = T1.PatientID
           AND T2.Interview_Date = (SELECT MAX(Interview_Date) 
                                      FROM @tmp T3
                                     WHERE T3.Interview_Date < T1.Interview_Date
                                       AND T3.PatientID = T1.PatientID
                                       -- or whatever PK that makes the row unique for the patient.
                                   )
       ) AS [Alcohol Use Rate change]
      ,Avg_Drug_Use_Month
       -
       (SELECT Avg_Drug_Use_Month
          FROM @tmp T2
         WHERE T2.PatientID = T1.PatientID
           AND T2.Interview_Date = (SELECT MAX(Interview_Date) 
                                      FROM @tmp T3
                                     WHERE T3.Interview_Date < T1.Interview_Date
                                       AND T3.PatientID = T1.PatientID
                                       -- or whatever PK makes the row unique for the patient.
                                   )
       ) AS [Drug Use Rate change]
  FROM @tmp T1
ORDER BY PatientID, Interview_Date
```

Use such a query as the dataset for SSRS.